# Is it possible to find if a value is present in Array without looping in mapbasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

How to find a  value is present in array without looping ?

```
e.g.
For i=1 TO ubount(Array)
  Find if value is present
Next
```

or some more direct statement like

```
Array.contains(somevalue) like in java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own function to do that really isn't that hard:

```
Function ARRContainsValue(arrValues() As String, ByVal sValue As String) As Logical

Dim i As Integer

ARRContainsValue = false

    For i = 1 To Ubound(arrValues)
        If arrValues(i) = sValue Then
            ARRContainsValue = true
            Exit Function       
        End if  
    Next

End Function
```

Note that this only works with String based arrays. You would need to write specific functions for each array types (Integer, Date, etc)